# gwt-openlayers - save modified object in PostGIS

Tags: openlayers

I'm new using gwt-openlayers. I try to modify a geometry in PostGIS DB. I can modify it in UI but I can't be able to save the modified geometry.
Here is my code to edit and save:

```
private void saveFeature(WFSProtocol wfsProtocol, Vector wfsLayer, SaveStrategy saveStrategy) {
    Callback callbackSave = new Callback()
    {
        public void computeResponse(Response response)
        {
            System.out.println("Saved: " + response.getRequestType());
         }
     };
     saveStrategy.save();
     WFSProtocolCRUDOptions saveOptions = new WFSProtocolCRUDOptions(callbackSave);
     wfsProtocol.commit(wfsLayer.getFeatures(), saveOptions);

}
private void editableLayer(Vector wfsLayer, Map map, VectorOptions vectorOptions, SaveStrategy saveStrategy) {
    //Create some styles for the wfs
    final Style normalStyle = new Style(); //the normal style
    normalStyle.setStrokeWidth(3);
    normalStyle.setStrokeColor("#FF0000");
    normalStyle.setFillColor("#FFFF00");
    normalStyle.setFillOpacity(0.8);
    normalStyle.setStrokeOpacity(0.8);
    final Style selectedStyle = new Style(); //the style when a feature is selected, or temporaly selected
    selectedStyle.setStrokeWidth(3);
    selectedStyle.setStrokeColor("#FFFF00");
    selectedStyle.setFillColor("#FF0000");
    selectedStyle.setFillOpacity(0.8);
    selectedStyle.setStrokeOpacity(0.8);
    final StyleMap styleMap = new StyleMap(normalStyle, selectedStyle,
                                           selectedStyle);
    wfsLayer.setStyleMap(styleMap);

    //Create a ModifyFeature control that enables WFS modification
    final ModifyFeatureOptions modifyFeatureControlOptions = new ModifyFeatureOptions();
    modifyFeatureControlOptions.setMode(ModifyFeature.RESHAPE); //options are RESHAPE, RESIZE, ROTATE and DRAG
    final ModifyFeature modifyFeatureControl = new ModifyFeature(wfsLayer,
                                                                 modifyFeatureControlOptions);

    map.addControl(modifyFeatureControl);
    modifyFeatureControl.activate();
    saveStrategy.activate();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem was connect to the geometry name. Default name for postgis is "the-geom" but in my case the name is "geom".

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was connect to the geometry name. In postgis the default name is "the-geom", in my case the name is "geom". I forget to specify it in WfsProtocolOptions:
wfsProtocolOptions.setGeometryName("geom");

Now all works!